# Custom IDResolver gets wrong target type

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I wrote this custom IDResolver:

```
final class MyIDResolver extends IDResolver {

    Map<String, Course> courses = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * @see com.sun.xml.bind.IDResolver#bind(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public void bind(String id, Object obj) throws SAXException {
        if (obj instanceof Course)
            courses.put(id, (Course)obj);
        else
            throw new SAXException("This " + obj.toString() + " cannot found");
    }

    /**
     * @see com.sun.xml.bind.IDResolver#resolve(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)
     */
    @Override
    public Callable<?> resolve(final String id, final Class targetType) throws SAXException {
        return new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                if (targetType == Course.class)
                    return courses.get(id);
                else
                    throw new ClassNotFoundException(targetType.toString() + " cannot found");
            }
        };
    }
 }
```

And I have two classes like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "course")
public class Course {
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlAttribute
    private int units;

    @XmlAttribute
    private Level level;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlElement(name = "pre")
    private ArrayList<Course> prerequisite;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlElement(name = "co")
    private ArrayList<Course> corequisite;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "dept")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public final class Department {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "courses")
    @XmlElement(name = "course")
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
}
```

And sample XML like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<dept name="ece">
    <courses>
    <course id="1" units="4" level="UNDERGRADUATE" name="Fundamentals of Programming"/>
    <course id="2" units="3" level="UNDERGRADUATE" name="Advanced Programming">
        <pre>1</pre>
    </course>
    </courses>
</dept>
```

And a simple main like this:

```java
unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileReader(arg0))
context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Department.class);
unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setProperty(IDResolver.class.getName(), new MyIDResolver());
```

The resolve() method of a custom IDResolver gets Object.class as targetType. But it should be Course.class. This results in wrong ID resolving. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use IDResolve when Department contains course. It should be used when Department want to reference to a Course. So for this reason when jaxb arrives a course inside of a department that it contains an element (here <pre>) it will pass *object.class* to your resolve function.

Comment: this is no answer for this question

Comment: Re *"IDResolve"*: Do you mean *"IDResolver"*?